# In WPF/Silverlight: Is it possible to bind a DataTable or an XML file to a ListView?

Tags: wpf, xml, silverlight, listview, datatable

Is it possible in WPF to bind a data matrix (data table or an XML file) to a ListView?

Given the following XML dataset:

```
<data>
  <cols>
    <col name="FirstName" />
    <col name="LastName" />
    <col name="Age" />
  </cols>
  <rows>
    <row>
      <col>Huey</col>
      <col>Freeman</col>
      <col>10</col>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col>Michael</col>
      <col>Caesar</col>
      <col>10</col>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col>Reiley</col>
      <col>Freeman</col>
      <col>8</col>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col>Cindy</col>
      <col null="true" />
      <col>9</col>
    </row>
    <row>
      <col />
      <col>Robert Jebediah Freeman</col>
      <col>70</col>
    </row>
  </rows>
</data>
```

Is it possible to bind this data to a ListView?

**Note that** the data columns are not pre-defined. It could of any type and the names vary.

P/S: I am aware of the DataGrid but it is too heavy for usage we just need to display the data.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XmlDataProvider for this.

```
XmlDataProvider data = new XmlDataProvider();

// you can load data from file/http/whatever

data.Source = "... some URL ...";

// *OR* you can go directly against an already existing XmlDocument

// data.Document = someXmlDocumentInstance;

data.XPath = "/books/book"; // specific to your schema obviously

myListView.ItemsSource = data.Data;
```

You can also setup a binding

```
Binding myBinding = new Binding();

myBinding.Source = data;

BindingOperations.SetBinding(myListView, ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, myBinding);
```

HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can bind this to a list view, however the columns will not auto-generate. You have to either build your own control that will do this, or find one that someone else has done already.

if you [google](http://www.google.com/search?rlz=1C1GGLS_enUS307US307&aq=0&oq=wpf+listview+auto&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=wpf+listview+auto+generate+columns) you will find all kinds of articles with and w/o code.